# how to calculate memory (in bytes) allocated by cudaMallocPitch

Tags: cuda

How can I get the total memory in bytes that was allocated by cudaMallocPitch? I need to send this data to another gpu through a library (Nvidia's NCCL) which expects a base pointer and number of bytes. I'm aware of the cudaMemcpy2D function for copying which unfortunately I cannot use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cudaMallocPitch` returns the pitch of the allocation in bytes. So if you called it like this:

```
void *devPtr;
size_t pitch;
cudaMallocPitch ( &devPtr, &pitch, width, height );
```

the size of the memory allocation is `pitch * height` bytes.